# Got two instances of struts2 action which is unexcepted

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am new to `spring` and `struts2`. I found there were two instances of my `action`, one with the `spring` injection and the other not. 
Here are my simple `WelcomeUserAction.java`

```
public class WelcomeUserAction extends ActionSupport {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private UserDaoImpl userDao;

    @Action(value="Welcome", results = {
            @Result(name ="success",location="pages/welcome_user.jsp"),
            @Result(name ="input",  location="pages/signup.jsp")
    })
    public String execute(){
        User user = new User();
        user.setPassword(password);
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setName(name);
        if (getUserDao() == null){
            System.out.println("getUserDao is null");
        }
        getUserDao().saveUser(user);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    /* getter and setters...  */
}
```

When I debug this application, I found even before the index page loaded, the spring was doing the injection. As the pic shows [image: spring injects at very very beginning]

And when the `WelcomeUserAction` starts working, there is another `WelcomeUserAction` instance, and the `spring` managing part,that is `userDao` became `null`.
[image: another instance of the struts2 action]

I don't know why this happens. Should I provide more information such as `applicationContext.xml` and `web.xml` ?

Comment: Why do you worry about instances of the actions, in Struts2 you may have as many instances as you want and they are all thread-safe.

Comment: @RomanC Well, I worry about that `spring` seems not inject to all the instances of the actions. In the second picture, `userDao` is `null` when I need it.

Comment: It depends on how are you wiring used in the spring bean configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I am missing. I forgot to add `struts2-spring-plugin.jar` to my buildpath.